# Is there a couchdb API that I can use to validate a user's password?

Tags: authentication, couchdb

I just want to validate a user's username and password without logging them in, is this possible?  I saw that I could use the _session API, but that would create sessions on the server, which I don't want to do: I just want to test if a given username/password pair is correct.

Comment: have you considered just creating the session and then immediately deleting it in your program?

Comment: @Greg yes I considered doing that, bit what I ended up doing was just to make a simple request using HTTP basic authentication and if I got a 200 response back then I knew the credentials were correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use [Basic Authentication](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/server/authn.html#basic-authentication) instead of the Cookie auth (_session API as you describe it).

Answer (score 0):

I’ve never tried that myself, but sounds sufficiently simple:

- Create a view where you use a string concatenated from username + password as key
- Query the key for a document that has a string you created by concatinating the user-supplied username + password as key.
- If there is a document that has the given string as key, the credentials are correct.

Notes:

- If needed, the user ID could be included in the same way
- Of course, you will want (or hopefully already have) a hashed password which includes a salt. Evidently, the same hashing and salting strategy must be used for both creating and querying the view.

Comment: Hmm, but from what I understand, the password is already stored hashed in couchdb's _user table, which means I would have to match the hashing algorithm used by couchdb, which I guess wouldn't be so horrible.  Just wanting to make sure there wasn't missing something